# Ember updating array does not update template

Tags: ember.js

I'm going mad with this problem:
I have a component with a template that uses a {{#each}} loop to iterate an array of comments;

```
comments: Ember.computed('commentsModel', function() {
    return this.get('commentsModel').toArray();
}),

actions: {
    addOne: function() {
        this.set('comments', [{content: 'agent k'}]);
    }
}
```

The component is called like this:

```
{{photo-comments commentsModel=model.comments}}
```

Where model.comments is returned by the model hook of the route;
When I click the button that triggers "addOne" event, the template updates correctly, all the comments are removed and only the new comment "agent k" is shown;

but if I want to ADD a comment into the comments array, instead of overwriting the whole array, it doesn't work;
I get no errors but the template simply ignores it and does not updates!

I tried with push:

```
actions: {
    addOne: function() {
        this.set('comments', this.get('comments').push({content: 'agent k'});
    }
}
```

with pushObject:

```
actions: {
    addOne: function() {
        this.set('comments', this.get('comments').pushObject({content: 'agent k'});
    }
}
```

nothing! Since this is driving me crazy, can someone tell what's wrong with this?

Template:

```
{{log comments}}
{{#each comments as |comment|}}
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-content">
            {{comment.username}}<br>
            {{comment.content}}
        </div>
        <div class="card-action">
            {{comment.createdAt}}
        </div>
    </div>
{{/each}}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the underlying issue here is that you're misusing the `Ember.computed` [helper](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.computed.html).

Your component should define a default value for the `comments` property, if there is one:

```
comments: null,

actions: {
    addOne: function() {
        this.get('comments').pushObject({content: 'agent k'});
    }
}
```

Your template should call the component by passing the model value:

```
{{photo-comments comments=model.comments}}
```

Assuming of course, that `model.comments` is available because it was retrieved by the route's model hook.

In your example code, you would have been attempting to push a new object to a computed property wrapping an array representation of a model, rather than pushing a new value to the model itself.

Comment: This is a solution that I've already tried, getting the error "internalModel.getRecord is not a function"; someone explained to me that this was due to my model being the result of a query, and so not writable; that's why I was converting the comments into an array

Comment: Ah, I think I misunderstood the use case there. If you are going to push data to a `RecordArray`, I would do the transformation outside of the component itself and pass the array into the component.

Comment: ok, if you can provide a working example would be great, since I spent days trying everything I know without being able to make it work; the problem is: I get some records (that are unwritable) so I must convert them into writable array, and push an object inside that array causing the template to update...

Comment: [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/hahoxipiri/edit?js,output) The key here I found is to utilize [pushObject](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.MutableArray.html#method_pushObject), against the array. In your example, you could modify the `RecordArray` in an afterModel hook (`afterModel(model) { model = model.toArray(); }`) in your route, which would then make it an instance of a `MutableArray` and allow `pushObject` to work from your component.

Comment: I've already tried also this approach; If I do `this.set('comments', this.get('comments').pushObject({content: 'agent k'}));`  in the action, from the template's log (see update in the question, I've added the template's code) says that comments is no more an array, but it's an object (the newly added record); can't understand why

Comment: It turnet out that I have to do only `this.get('comments').pushObject(newComment)`... exactly how was written in your asnwer ;) Thanks for help